# Can anyone tell me how this effect is achieved?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, slideshow

So in this website:
https://www.sohofarmhouse.com/hotel/farmyard-up

The background image is resized automatically when the screen size changes however the aspect ratio is always maintained.

My guess is it's something to do with div's within div's but please could someone break it down for me as I'd love to be able to achieve this in my own sites.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Just make use of basics of RWD?

Comment: This question is about an off-site resource and doesn't include any relevant details. If the link ever breaks or the contents of the page changes, this question will be of no use to anyone.

Comment: Have you used your browser's developer tools to look at the example site in question? Most times if there is a specific effect you want to go after that just involves styling, you should just inspect the example site and see how they achieved the effect. Oftentimes it's best to do some research before asking a question on here, and in this case looking at how the example effect was achieved should be the first step in your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are at least two ways to achieve this result. You can pick one of them depending on browsers compatibility.

1) You can choose a pure-css solution using a background image for your div and setting:

```
background-size: cover;
```

You cannot use this approach if IE8 is one of your target browsers.

2) You can use a javascript library. I often use a library called [jquery Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/). It's very easy to use.